# How to determine if a field is numeric and convert in the same where clause

Tags: sql-server

I have the following simple sql

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *
  FROM CallRecords
  where clientId = 4 and 
  resultcodeId > 1 and
  ISNUMERIC(extension) = 1 and 
  Convert(int,extension) > 72320 and Convert(int,extension) < 73000
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'b01004957003' to data type int.
```

Obviously one extension contain 'b01004957003'

However I thought sql would stop checking after the ISNUMERIC(extension) = 1

Any clues?

Comment: Don't use isnumeric in where clause instead use Case. Select Case when ISNUMERIC(extension) then .. Use convert extension here .. Else ... End

Comment: From http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/02/25/How-SQL-Server-short-circuits-WHERE-condition-evaluation.aspx : "As a developer you must be aware that SQL Server does not do short-circuiting like it is done in other programming languages and there's nothing you can do to force it to."

Comment: Not obviously.... if `clientId` or `resultcodeID` is varchar, then they too could contain that value and be failing. Post the datatype of each column involved. SQL does things in the order of the query plan and this might change from execution to execution.

Comment: the extension is the offender here, it contains the erronous data, the clientId and ResultCodeId are ints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keeping the convert in outer query

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT TOP 1000 *
        FROM   CallRecords
        WHERE  clientId = 4
               AND resultcodeId > 1
               AND Isnumeric(extension) = 1) A
WHERE  CONVERT(INT, extension) > 72320
       AND CONVERT(INT, extension) < 73000
```